# Adding a index to a dataframe by grouping the data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a problem in grouping the data and adding the index.

A new column index is to be added starting with 1 to n(eg: 5) and iterate from 1 again.
The value can be anything so basically after every n records the index should restart with 1.

original dataframe

| city | id |
| --- | --- |
| NYC | 101 |
| Jersey City | 102 |
| Hoboken | 103 |
| Buffalo | 104 |
| Philly | 105 |
| Edison | 106 |

Output dataframe something should look like

| city | id | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 101 | 1 |
| Jersey City | 102 | 2 |
| Hoboken | 103 | 3 |
| Buffalo | 104 | 4 |
| Philly | 105 | 5 |
| Edison | 106 | 1 |
| trenton | 107 | 2 |

Comment: Is there a special key/value/column that you want to use in order to create those groups or just bulk them as equal-size ones?

Comment: @NirHedvat column "id" is a reference column with ascending order and group the rows into n(eg: 5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ntile in spark? It will make sure you have the id's placed in 5 buckets ranking 1 to 5 always.

```
WindowSpec window = Window.orderBy(col("id").asc());
dataset.withColumn("index", ntile(5).over(window)).show();
```

Comment: Neethu, Thanks for reply. when applied ntile function I see the sequence of index repeating something like this but the output dataframe should contain 1 to 5 in the same order and then repeat with 1 again 
|       city| id|index|
+-----------+---+-----+
|        NYC|101|    1|
|Jersey City|102|    1|
|    Hoboken|103|    2|
|    Buffalo|104|    2|
|     Philly|105|    3|
|     Edison|106|    4|
|    Trenton|107|    5|
+-----------+---+-----+

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data
  .withColumn("groupId", ceil(col("id") / lit(5)))
  .withColumn("index", row_number() over Window.partitionBy("groupId").orderBy("id"))
  .drop(col("groupId"))
```

Output (tested):

```
+-----------+---+-----+
|       city| id|index|
+-----------+---+-----+
|        NYC|101|    1|
|Jersey City|102|    2|
|    Hoboken|103|    3|
|    Buffalo|104|    4|
|     Philly|105|    5|
|     Edison|106|    1|
|    Trenton|107|    2|
+-----------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Nir, Thanks for reply. This code works for lit(5) but when if changed to someother number it fails. I tried with 3 and 7

Comment: The buckets which result are according to 'id'. It iterates over them. You will always have 1 or 2 groups (at the most) with less than n rows. That's the remainder. Unless you want to group the rows according to a different column, that's the solution. Id is the group key (not only in my solution, but in your question).
Can you please tell me what would you like to get differently?

Comment: What you want is to group all records and then perform the id generation. You could that but I wouldn't recommend it. You will encounter severe performance issues (memory in particular). Take a look at this: https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6. I can offer you a different approach, which will answer your specific needs, but that won't be suitable for large datasets.